# Flutter : Any suggestions for widgets that can be used for bumble graph like this?

Tags: android, ios, flutter, mobile, widget

[Any suggestions for widgets that can be used for bumble graph like this?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1vhB.png)

Answer (score 6):

You can use this package https://pub.dev/packages/syncfusion_flutter_sliders , and just add multiple values like for example :

```
SfRangeValues _values = SfRangeValues(40.0, 80.0);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return Scaffold(
     appBar: AppBar(
       title: const Text('Syncfusion Flutter Range Slider'),
     ),
     body: SfRangeSlider(
        min: 0.0,
        max: 100.0,
        values: _values,
        interval: 20,
        showTicks: true,
        showLabels: true,
        enableTooltip: true,
        minorTicksPerInterval: 1,
        onChanged: (SfRangeValues values){
          setState(() {
            _values = values;
          });
        },
      ),
   );
}
```

while you can add values to SfRangeValues(40.0, 80.0) as you like